Mysterious `R CMD check` "NOTE": "Warning: trimming empty <li>" even when line is not empty
Whenever I submit my R package to CRAN, the automated check returns these NOTES:
* checking HTML version of manual ... [34s] NOTE
Found the following HTML validation problems:
fastData.html:67:1 (fastData.Rd:24): Warning: trimming empty <li>
fasterRaster.html:138:1 (fasterRaster.Rd:50): Warning: trimming empty <li>
fasterRaster.html:617:1 (fasterRaster.Rd:237): Warning: trimming empty <li>

But in the documentation, these appear as (just showing the first one from above--I'm using roxygen2):
#' Rasters (objects of class `SpatRaster` from the **terra** package, saved as GeoTIFF files):
#' * [madChelsa]: Bioclimatic variables
#' * [madCover]: Land cover
#' * [madElev]: Elevation
#' * [madForest2000]: Forest cover in year 2000
#' * [madForest2014]: Forest cover in year 2014
#' * [madLANDSAT]: Surface reflectance in 2023
#' * [madPpt], [madTmin], [madTmax]: Rasters of mean monthly precipitation, and minimum and maximum temperature.

However, in the .Rd files, these places do indeed have an empty line
\itemize{
\item \link{madChelsa}: Bioclimatic variables
\item \link{madCover}: Land cover
\item 
\item \link{madForest2000}: Forest cover in year 2000
\item \link{madForest2014}: Forest cover in year 2014
\item \link{madLANDSAT}: Surface reflectance in 2023
\item \link{madPpt}, \link{madTmin}, \link{madTmax}: Rasters of mean monthly precipitation, and minimum and maximum temperature.
}

Why is the line with #' * [madElev]: Elevation getting skipped here?
I do indeed have a help page for madElev, and it opens when I devtools::load_all() or install the package and do ?madElev.
I thought it might have been a character invisible to my IDE that got inserted somehow, so in another part of the document, I typed out the entire line before, including, and after the offending line, then pasted it over the offending area. I get the same outcome in the .Rd files and thus the same NOTE.
Also, this NOTE does not appear when I run devtools::check() on my package locally--only after submitting to CRAN. But the .Rd files are clearly missing these lines.

A fix to this--which I consider "hacky", and  not the real answer--is to replace the link in the lines that are omitted with "[item][item]". For example, "#' * [madElev][madElev]: Elevation". It's not a great solution because the underlying problem remains and I can't devtools::check() for this.
